Manual syscall gives STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Im trying to call NtAllocateVirtualMemory using the syscall instruction but it returns the error STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
I tried running it as administrator but it gave me the same error. Im expecting for it to allocate memory at a random base address.
my cpp code:
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#define NT_SUCCESS(Status) ((NTSTATUS)(Status) >= 0)

extern "C" NTSTATUS SysNtAllocateVirtualMemory(HANDLE ProcessHandle, PVOID * BaseAddress, ULONG ZeroBits, PULONG RegionSize, ULONG AllocationType, ULONG Protect);

int main()
{
    PVOID buffer = nullptr;

    printf("[+] Calling NtAlocateVirtualMemory.\n");
    NTSTATUS status = SysNtAllocateVirtualMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), &buffer, 0, (PULONG)0x1000, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        printf("[!] Unable to allocate memory: %x\n", status);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Memory: %p\n", buffer);
    printf("[+] Call successful.\n");
}

my asm code:
.code
    SysNtAllocateVirtualMemory PROC
        mov r10, rcx
        mov eax, 00000018
        syscall
        ret
    SysNtAllocateVirtualMemory ENDP
END


For starters, the syscall number is 0x18 (hex).

I had the wrong system id number its meant to be 18h instead of 00000018
